# Neo4j How to create horizontal, vertical and diagonal relationships?

Tags: neo4j, relationships

I'm new in neo4j and i need some advices or suggestions for creating the relationships:

I have 70 nodes, that represent every slot of a matrix[10][7]. Every Node has a (i,j) as a property

```
for(int i = S_N; i <= F_N; i++){//10 rows S_N= 5735, F_N=5744
      for(int j = S_E; j <= F_E; j++){//7 columns S_E=589, F_E=595

          Node gridNode = graphDb.createNode(label);
          gridNode.setProperty("id", id);
          gridNode.setProperty("name", "Grid" + id);
          gridNode.setProperty("easting", j);
          gridNode.setProperty("northing", i);
           id++;  
             }
         }
```

How can i create Horizontal, Vertical and Diagonals(including diagonal inverse) Relations bwt the nodes in a simple manner? Something like this:

[image: Matrix Relations]
And also, in every relation i need to add two properties, whose values will be computed randomly

I have more than 200 relations, and this is only considering one direction (not both) btw the nodes.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From perspective of Neo4j there is not something like horizontal and vertical relationships.

I suggest you to create ordinary relationship and add label, which will represent type of the relationship.

Example in Cypher

```
CREATE (e00:Element {x:0, y:0})
CREATE (e01:Element {x:0, y:1})
CREATE (e10:Element {x:1, y:0})
CREATE (e11:Element {x:1, y:1})

CREATE (e00)-[rh1:HORIZONTAL]->(e01)
CREATE (e00)-[rd1:DIAGONAL]->(e10)
CREATE (e00)-[rv1:VERTICAL]->(e11)

CREATE (e10)-[rh2:HORIZONTAL]->(e11)
CREATE (e10)-[rd2:DIAGONAL]->(e01)
CREATE (e10)-[rv2:VERTICAL]->(e00)
```

Here is JAVA pseudocode to show idea how to do it

```
class Coordinates {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

private RelationshipType getRelationShipType(Coordinates coordinates, int x, int y) {
    int currentX = coordinates.x;
    int currentY = coordinates.y;

    if (currentX == x && currentY < y) {
        return DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Vertical");
    }

    if (currentX < x && currentY == y) {
        return DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Horizontal");
    }

    return DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Diagonal");
}


int columns = 10;
int rows = 10;
String nodeLabel = "NodeLabel";

Map<Coordinates,Node> matrix = new HashMap<>();

for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        Node node = database.createNode(DynamicLabel.label(nodeLabel));
            node.setProperty("propertyName", "propertyValue");
            matrix.put(new Coordinates(x, y), node);
        }
    }

for (Coordinates coordinates : matrix.keySet()) {
    final Node startNode = matrix.get(coordinates);

    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            final Node endNode = matrix.get(new Coordinates(x, y));

            if (endNode != null) {
                RelationshipType relationshipType = getRelationShipType(coordinates, x, y);
                    startNode.createRelationshipTo(endNode, relationshipType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you MicTech. Well, i don't need to define the name of the relation, the type is the same. The thing is, this time i have 70 nodes, but it may change, so i would like to write the code for any number of nodes. How can be written in java code. I thought about do it inside a loop, like Relation = Node(i,j). createRelationTo(Node(i, j+1)). The "i", "j" values are node properties, how to get a Node in java given two properties.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, could you please tell me what is the purpose of a DynamicRelationship type and when should i use it?